# Is there a name for a word or term that is persistently re-coined?

Tags: phrase-requests

I came across the term "sex film actress" in the Op-Ed column [The Disposable Woman](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/03/04/opinion/04holmes.html?_r=1&ref=opinion). I could guess what the phrase meant, as "sex worker" is a new term for "prostitute", and therefore "sex film actress" would be the equivalent for "porn star".

I checked if this term had been used before, and there were a smattering of uses, but it looked so infrequent it seemed as if the term was coined each time. Is there a name for such a phenomenon?

Comment: What about a programming language that's constantly re-invented. *Lisp*?

Comment: @JaredUpdike - If they could say it clearly the first time they wouldn't have to keep repeating it.

Comment: ... A bad penny?

Comment: How can a word that is coined be reminted? Sex film actress means: an actress in sex films. Who knows if she is a porn star. Sex film actress is not a "term". Sometimes people just write things. Not every grouping of words are "terms". Is "action hero movie" a "term"? Is "romance comedy writer" a term? Creating euphemisms or new PC terms is not re-coining just reconning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's currently a word for it, but you could probably get away with calling it a *re-neologism*.  (Although in the case of "sex film actress", the re-phrasing is so pointless even by PC standards that I'd have to label it a "useless euphemism".)

Comment: I was going to call it political correctness, but I could sympathize with why the term was used.

Comment: Also there’s probably plenty who may fall into the actress category but not the “star” category.

Comment: @Jim but see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15321/why-is-anyone-in-a-porn-movie-considered-a-porn-star?noredirect=1&lq=1 ...

Comment: @Hellion - Interesting.

Answer (score 3):

"sex film actress" is more precise than "porn star" as there are many kinds of porn media (and many kinds of porn) and "sex film" narrows it down a lot. Also, "actress" narrows it down to "female" but that's probably redundant based on the context. So using the phrase "sex film actress" might not be a euphemism nor an attempt at being PC, but rather an attempt at being explicit.

Given that this is not a word but rather a phrase with a pretty obvious meaning, it doesn't strike me as being remarkable.  If I described Lon Chaney as a "silent film actor" you should know immediately what that means even if "silent film actor" isn't a set phrase.

Comment: Apart from when "porn" is used metaphorically (such as "food porn"), when is "porn" different from "sex film"?

Comment: @Andrew: well, if it's just photos of porn?

Comment: A "sex film" is synonymous with a "porn film".  I'm not sure why one would need to distinguish between an individual who acts in pornographic films and an individual who poses for pornographic photos.  The necessity for differentiating between the two nearly-identical professions is almost nonexistent, as far as I can tell.  In any case, I find it extremely doubtful that the original author used the term as a deliberate differentiation from a person who poses nude for still photos.

Comment: @Dr.Funk - Of course, you're not a sex film actress.  (Are you?)

Comment: someone who only poses for still photos would not be a star.

Answer (score 0):

The term ***compulsive euphemization*** fits in the context of political correctness.